# Using ifelse across separate dataframes in R

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement, data-wrangling

I have two dataframes:

1. Dataframe: "Averages" consists of one column Lat, and about a thousand columns named ASV+running number

```
> dput(averages[1:10, c(1: 16)])
structure(list(Lat = c(-59.99833333, -59.33383333, -58.66866667, 
-58.00066667, -57.33483333, -56.67116667, -53.00033333, -52.335, 
-51.67116667, -51.00016667), asv_3 = c(1838.5, 275.5, 175, 733.5, 
1510.5, 2538.5, 3451.5, 1084.5, 811.5, 545.5), asv_4 = c(2758.5, 
1101.5, 1679, 676, 844, 888.5, 738.5, 1051.5, 1057, 777.5), asv_5 = c(170.5, 
245, 94, 81.5, 195, 80.5, 262, 335, 301, 161), asv_7 = c(4632, 
1019.5, 1790, 27, 34.5, 19, 3, 0, 0, 1.5), asv_8 = c(743, 849, 
1109.5, 450.5, 408.5, 404, 258, 212.5, 297.5, 212.5), asv_9 = c(625.5, 
2234, 1726, 3031.5, 5130.5, 368, 21, 0, 0, 0), asv_10 = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1198, 3006, 1740.5, 1198), asv_11 = c(0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1334.5, 3013, 2209.5, 1619), asv_12 = c(822, 485, 346, 
221.5, 239.5, 191.5, 250, 232.5, 296, 169.5), asv_14 = c(183, 
26.5, 16, 333.5, 1031, 1520.5, 409.5, 195, 51.5, 63), asv_15 = c(603.5, 
1365.5, 1246.5, 1192.5, 1312.5, 765.5, 65, 56.5, 95.5, 80), asv_17 = c(2657.5, 
1713, 1683, 75, 48.5, 45, 141.5, 100, 178, 60.5), asv_18 = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2.5), asv_19 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 36.5, 
25.5, 39.5, 51.5), asv_20 = c(0, 1.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 292, 673, 512.5, 
319)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

2. Dataframe: "ranges". I have created this based on my dataframe 1 Averages. It consists of the columns ASV and V1 and contains the ASVs from dataframe 1, and range values stored in column V1.

```
> dput(ranges[1:15, c(1: 2)])
structure(list(ASV = c("asv_3", "asv_4", "asv_5", "asv_7", "asv_8", 
"asv_9", "asv_10", "asv_11", "asv_12", "asv_14", "asv_15", "asv_17", 
"asv_18", "asv_19", "asv_20"), V1 = c(30.00133333, 30.00133333, 
30.00133333, 16.00083333, 30.00133333, 9.66466666, 22.00283333, 
10.004, 30.00133333, 16.46566666, 17.002, 17.99783333, 20.00266667, 
23.00333333, 29.33683333)), row.names = c(NA, 15L), class = "data.frame")
```

3. I now want to create a third dataframe. It should have the column names from dataframe 1, as well as all values for column Lat. I want to fill this dataframe as follows: If an ASV column in dataframe 1 (averages) has a value > 0, I want to paste the respective range value from dataframe 2 (ranges) into my new third dataframe; if the value is 0, then the value in the new dataframe should be 0.
   E.g. for ASV_3 in dataframe 1, I have a value of 1838.5 at Lat -59.99833333. This is greater than 0, so I want to paste the range value (30.00133333) from dataframe 2 into my new dataframe.

I hope that makes sense. I have tried to do this using `ifelse`, but I have not even come close enough to warrant pasting my code attempts here. I would really appreciate any help!

EDIT: Added larger portion of dataframe to include 0 values

Comment: In your example data, every ASV value in `averages` is greater than 0, and all of the ASVs (3, 4, 5) have the same `V1` value (30.0).  This will result in every value not in `Lat` being 30.  If you expect to have cases where `V1` differs (like ASV7 or 8), or averages is 0, it would be helpful to include those, with expected output, in your example.  Otherwise it may be hard to verify whether an answer is working based on the data provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adjusting `averages` slightly to allow for more conditions to be evaluated - here's one way to use `ifelse` to achieve what you want:

```
library(dplyr)

averages |> 
  mutate(across(-Lat, \(val) 
    ifelse(
      val > 0, 
      ranges[ranges$ASV == cur_column(), 'V1'], 
      # alt: ranges |> filter(ASV == cur_column()) |> pull(V1)
      0
    )
  ))

# A tibble: 4 × 4
    Lat asv_7 asv_4 asv_5
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 -60.0   0    30.0  30.0
2 -59.3  16.0  30.0  30.0
3 -58.7   0    30.0  30.0
4 -58.0  16.0  30.0  30.0
```

Adjusted data from OP:

```
averages <- structure(list(Lat = c(-59.99833333, -59.33383333, -58.66866667, 
                             -58.00066667), asv_7 = c(-1838.5, 275.5, -175, 733.5), asv_4 = c(2758.5, 

averages
# A tibble: 4 × 4
    Lat  asv_7 asv_4 asv_5
  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 -60.0 -1838. 2758. 170. 
2 -59.3   276. 1102. 245  
3 -58.7  -175  1679   94  
4 -58.0   734.  676   81.5
```

Comment: > averages |> 
Error: unexpected '>' in "averages |>"
>   mutate(across(-Lat, \(val) 
Error: unexpected input in "  mutate(across(-Lat, \"
>                 ifelse(
+                   val > 0, 
+                   ranges[ranges$ASV == cur_column(), 'V1'], 
+                   # alt: ranges |> filter(ASV == cur_column()) |> pull(V1)
+                   0
+                 )
Error in ifelse(val > 0, ranges[ranges$ASV == cur_column(), "V1"], 0) : 
  object 'val' not found
>   ))
Error: unexpected ')' in "  )" @andrew_reece

Comment: Possible you have an older version of R?  The pipe operator `|>` was introduced in R 4.1.0 - you can also use `%>%`.  The code runs correctly as provided.

Comment: That still does not work unfortunately @andrew_reece. 
> averages %>%
+   mutate(across(-Lat, \(val) 
Error: unexpected input in:
"averages %>%
  mutate(across(-Lat, \"
>                 ifelse(
+                   val > 0, 
+                   ranges[ranges$ASV == cur_column(), 'V1'], 
+                   # alt: ranges |> filter(ASV == cur_column()) |> pull(V1)
+                   0
+                 )
Error in ifelse(val > 0, ranges[ranges$ASV == cur_column(), "V1"], 0) : 
  object 'val' not found
>   ))
Error: unexpected ')' in "  )"

Comment: I just tried it on my company PC and it does work there - so it seems to be a version control issue. Is there anything else you can identify except the pipe operator that may cause an issue with an older version @andrew_reece? I am quite reluctant to update everything as present as I'm months away from turning in my PhD thesis and have had massive headaches with dependency hell in the past

Comment: in the code you posted above (in your "That still does not.." comment, you have extra `+` characters - those look like they were added in a console copy/paste.  Take those out, should run.  As for version issues, I can relate.  It really depends on how your thesis machine is set up, maybe consider copying that environment exactly (with `packrat` or a similar package) so you can test on other machines.

Comment: Good luck with your thesis.  If this question solves your issue, please mark it checked to let others know it has been resolved.

Answer (score 1):

If you're struggling with dependencies, this base R solution should work

```
third_dataframe = Averages
for (row in rownames(ranges)){
range = ranges[row, "ASV"]
V1 = ranges[row, "V1"]
third_dataframe[third_dataframe[,range] > 0, range] = V1
}
```